# issue with running java me source code on emulator

Tags: java-me

I just finished installing all the necessary tools for Java ME and I am getting the following error:

```
Installing suite from: http://127.0.0.1:58255/Homework1.jad

*** Error ***
A problem occured during deploying application from http://127.0.0.1:58255/Homework1.jad
Reason:
Either the configuration or profile is not supported.
```

Comment: Did you check your system minimal config ?

Comment: What IDE and Toolkit you are using? Also check MIDP and CLDC version on your project.

Comment: Eclipse and the latest java me 3.0 toolkit

Answer (score 0):

It can be either the configuration or profile.

Compare the Microedition Configuration (CLDC) and Microedition Profile at `Application Descriptor` against your Device Configurations in `Project->Properties->Java ME->Edit`

They should be the same.